# C program only running the first loop and then stopping

Tags: c

Every time I try and run only the first loop runs. It ask how many items were sold and then just stops running. I'm not really sure what I did wrong. If anyone has any tips that would be great(story if there's some formatting issues, SO wouldn't let me post the question without them).

Everything else looks fine but if any other improvements could be made please let me know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int digit(char term[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int val = 0;
    while (term[i] != '\0')
    {
        val = val * 10 + term[i] - '0';
        i++; 
    } 
    return val;
}

void error()
{
    printf("Error: Sales figures must be numbers.\n");
    printf("Please try again.\n");
}

bool isnumber(char term[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (term[i])
    {
        if( isdigit(term[i]) == 0)
        {
            return false;
            i++;
        }    
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int sales[3][2], costs[3] = {3, 4, 1}, weekends[2] = {0, 0};

    int i, j, val;

    char term[100];

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Number of Bagel sales on Saturday: ");
        scanf("%s", term);
        if( isnumber(term) == false)
        {
            error;
        }
        else
        {
            sales[0][0] = digit(term);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Number of Flatbread sales on Saturday: ");
        scanf("%s", term);
        if( isnumber(term) == false)
        {
            error;
        }
        else
        {
            sales[1][0] = digit(term);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    while (1)
    {
        
        printf("Number of Muffin sales on Saturday: ");
        scanf("%s", term);
        if (isnumber(term) == false)
        {
            error;
        }
        else
        {
            sales[2][0] = digit(term);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Number of Bagel sales on Sunday: ");
        scanf("%s", term);
        if( isnumber(term) == false)
        {
            error;
        }
        else
        {
            sales[0][1] = digit(term);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Number of Flatbread sales on Sunday: ");
        scanf("%s", term);
        if( isnumber(term) == false)
        {
            error;
        }
        else
        {
            sales[1][1] = digit(term);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Number of Muffin sales on Sunday: ");
        scanf("%s", term);
        if( isnumber(term) == false)
        {
            error;
        }
        else
        {
            sales[2][1] = digit(term);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 2, i++;)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3, j++;)
        {
            weekends[i] += costs[j] * sales[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3, i++;)
    {
        printf("%d", costs[i]);
        
    }
    printf(".");
    for (i = 0; i < 3, i++;)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 2, j++;)
        {
            printf("%d", sales[i][j]);
        }
        if (i == 0)
        {
            printf(" = ");
            printf("%d %d", weekends[0], weekends[1]);
        }
        printf("\n    ");
    }
    
    printf("\nTotal sales on Saturday: $%d", weekends[0]);
    printf("\nTotal sales on Sunday: $%d", weekends[1]);
    printf("\nTotal sales over the weekend: $%d", weekends[0] + weekends[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `error;` is not a valid function invocation.

Comment: to elaborate on Eugene's comment, it should be `error();` not `error;`

Comment: Use a debugger and step through your code statement by statement, and the problem will become obvious.

Comment: You have an infinite loop in `isnumber()`, since it never increments `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in `isnumber()`. It will return `false` if the first character is not a digit. But if the first character is a digit, it never increments `i`, so it keeps testing the first character repeatedly.

`i++` should not be in the `if` statement.

```
bool isnumber(char term[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (term[i])
    {
        if(!isdigit(term[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And as others have pointed out, you need to put `()` after `error` to call it.

Answer (score 0):

As for your programming stopping; you use `isdigit` on line 30 without declaring it.

Along that, you use `error` everywhere without invoking it. Use `error()` to invoke the function and print the error-information.

Just a small formatting tip as well: instead of `if (something == false)` use `if (!something)`

Answer (score -1):

Your use of `error;` is incorrect. You should write `error();` instead.

Comment: Tried doing that and i'm still getting the same error unfortunately.