# Can't get my C program to print the output

Tags: c

When I go to print the output of the program everything shows up as zero. I think the variable aren't storing themselves, but I'm not totally sure. When I go to look over everything, it looks right but clearly isn't. Any help would be really appreciated. Sorry if the formatting seems a little off, Stack Overflow wouldn't accept it otherwise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int digit(char term[])
{
int i = 0;
int val = 0;
while (term[i] != '\0')
{
    val = val * 10 + term[i] - '0';
     
} 
i++;
return val;
}

void error()
{
printf("Error: Sales figures must be numbers.\n");
printf("Please try again.\n");
}

bool isnumber(char term[])
{
int i = 0;
while (term[i])
{
    if( isdigit(term[i]) == 0)
    {
        return false;
        i++;
    }    
}
return true;
}

int main()
{
int sales[3][2], costs[3] = {3, 4, 1}, weekends[2] = {0, 0};

int i, j, val;

char term[100];

while (1)
{
    printf("Number of Bagel sales on Saturday: ");
    scanf("%s", term);
    if( isnumber(term) == false)
    {
        error();
    }
    else
    {
        sales[0][0] = digit(term);
        break;
    }
}

while (1)
{
    printf("Number of Flatbread sales on Saturday: ");
    scanf("%s", term);
    if( isnumber(term) == false)
    {
        error();
    }
    else
    {
        sales[1][0] = digit(term);
        break;
    }
}

while (1)
{
    
    printf("Number of Muffin sales on Saturday: ");
    scanf("%s", term);
    if (isnumber(term) == false)
    {
        error();
    }
    else
    {
        sales[2][0] = digit(term);
        break;
    }
}

while (1)
{
    printf("Number of Bagel sales on Sunday: ");
    scanf("%s", term);
    if( isnumber(term) == false)
    {
        error();
    }
    else
    {
        sales[0][1] = digit(term);
        break;
    }
}

while (1)
{
    printf("Number of Flatbread sales on Sunday: ");
    scanf("%s", term);
    if( isnumber(term) == false)
    {
        error();
    }
    else
    {
        sales[1][1] = digit(term);
        break;
    }
}

while (1)
{
    printf("Number of Muffin sales on Sunday: ");
    scanf("%s", term);
    if( isnumber(term) == false)
    {
        error();
    }
    else
    {
        sales[2][1] = digit(term);
        break;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 2, i++;)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 3, j++;)
    {
        weekends[i] += costs[j] * sales[i][j];
    }
}

printf("\n");
for (i = 0; i < 3, i++;)
{
    printf("%d", costs[i]);
    
}
printf(".");
for (i = 0; i < 3, i++;)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 2, j++;)
    {
        printf("%d", sales[i][j]);
    }
    if (i == 0)
    {
        printf(" = ");
        printf("%d %d", weekends[0], weekends[1]);
    }
    printf("\n    ");
}

printf("\nTotal sales on Saturday: $%d", weekends[0]);
printf("\nTotal sales on Sunday: $%d", weekends[1]);
printf("\nTotal sales over the weekend: $%d", weekends[0] + weekends[1]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bad indentation - cannot read.

Comment: I'm sure it can, if you ask it nicely ;)

Comment: what is your input? I don't see how you make it past `isnumber` if you do enter a valid number. `i` is never updated (even if `isdigit == 0` since you `return false` before `i++`). You'll spin on `term[0]` forever.

Comment: ah, and I see this was answered in your question two hours ago, yet still unfixed here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/67062312/3476780

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing i in the loop.  Your code for `digit` is:

```
 int digit(char term[])
    {
    int i = 0;
    int val = 0;
    while (term[i] != '\0')
    {
        val = val * 10 + term[i] - '0';
         
    } 
    i++;   /* ---- this is outside the loop !! */
    return val;
    }
```

But it ought to look like:

```
int 
digit(const char *term)
{
    int val = 0;
    while( *term != '\0' ){
        val = val * 10 + *term - '0'; 
        term += 1;    
    } 
    return val;
 }
```

Comment: ....which cannot be easily seen because of the bad indentation:(